# Determinants and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

[image: question]

Hello, I'm trying to work through this question.

I define linearly independent as:

$a_1*v_1+a_2*v_2+...+a_n*v_n = 0$ iff every $a_i=0$.

I also know that an eigenvector is a vector $v$ such that:

$T(v)=\lambda*v$

where $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Apply change of basis wrt $v_i$s to $T$ to obtain a diagonal matrix with these eigenvalues, whose determinant will be their product. Changing basis on a matrix amounts to conjugating it by the appropriate matrix, which does not affect determinant.

Comment: @seaturtles can you give me an example please?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Remember that eigenvectors of linear mappings are by definition non-zero.

Take one eigenvector $\;v_i\;$ from each different eigenvalue $\;\lambda_i\;$ and prove this $\;n\;$ eigenvectors are linearly independent and thus they are a basis for $\;V\;$.

Calculate the matrix representation of $\;T\;$ wrt the basis $\;\{v_1,...,v_n\}\;$ . Further hint:

$$Tv_i=\lambda_iv_i=0\cdot v_1+\ldots+0\cdot v_{i-1}+\lambda_iv_i+0\cdot v_{i+1}+\ldots+0\cdot v_n$$

Calculate now the determinant of $\;V\;$ wrt the above representation, remembering that the determinant is invariant wrt choice of basis.

Answer (score 1):

Since $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ are $n$ linearly independant in a linear space $V$ with dimension $n$ the the family $\mathcal B=(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ is a basis of $V$ but since these vectors are eigenvectors of $T$ then the matrix of $T$ relative to the basis $\mathcal B$ is diagonal:
$$[T]_{\mathcal B}=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$$
hence
$$\det (T)=\det([T]_{\mathcal B})=\prod_{k=1}^n\lambda_k$$

Answer (score 0):

Look at diagonalizing the matrix representation of $T$. So $T = QDQ^{-1}$, where $Q$ is your matrix from the eigenvectors and $D$ is the diagonal matrix of the eigenvalues. We note $det(Q) = \frac{1}{det(Q^{-1}}$. It should be fairly straight-forward to get $det(T) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_{i}$.